# What does over and underestimation of test error in Cross Validation mean?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, training-error

I know it's a naive question but i am having a hard time to understand what does it mean by the term under/over estimation of test error in Cross Validation.
For example the following snippet is taken out of the ISLR book,

*Since statistical methods tend to perform worse when trained on fewer observations, this suggests that the validation set error rate may tend to `overestimate the test error` rate for the model fit on the entire data set.*